# How to customize a widget to dynamically fetch data from an API?

Tags: widget, elementor

I'm working on a project using Elementor, and I'm trying to customize a widget to dynamically fetch data from an API. Specifically, I want to know if there's a way to achieve this without using the Elementor developer API.

Has anyone successfully implemented such customization within Elementor, and if so, could you share some insights or code snippets on how to accomplish this?

I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide. Thanks!